# Bash df command - Get used space in one bash command without unneccessary output

Tags: bash, grep, debian

When running df on debian, the output shows me everything of about used space, the dir and so on like this:

```
    Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay         19484408 4980572  13661276  27% /
tmpfs              65536       0     65536   0% /dev
/dev/sda1       19484408 4980572  13661276  27% /etc/hosts
shm                65536       0     65536   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             990656       0    990656   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs             990656       0    990656   0% /sys/firmware
```

I only need the total used space in percentage like this: `27%`

Is there any way to filter that out only using bash in one command? i tried very long and didnt found a fitting solution

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @0stone0 That's a [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) as such.

Comment: Yea your right, started with grep + cut, changed to awk. The dupe will answer op ;)

Comment: df is not a bash command but a Linux/BSD/Unix utility.